# Wholesale orders

Tags: magento2, inventory

Is there any way to set order quantities by dozens in Magento 2 for wholesale customers?

We want customer to be able to select from **Qty dropdown**:

```
12
24
36
48
64
72
96
```

Comment: Could you check this one. http://inchoo.net/magento-2/add-qty-increment-buttons-to-product-page/

Comment: In Configuration > Catalog > Inventory I set Enable Qty Increments to 'Yes' and then set the Qty Increments to 12 but when I entered '18' in the product Qty on the product's page the cart showed '18' for that product. Why does it do that. It's only supposed to be increments of 12.

Comment: On some products I need to set increments to 6, 12, 24, 36, 48, 54, 60, 72, 84, 96. So, they would be mainly by dozens, but the minimum is 6.